# Is every number $10^{2n}+1$ with $n>1$ composite?

Tags: number-theory

If you put in `[primes(10**i+1) for i in range(1,23) if i%2==0]` to Python it certainly seems so. But I don't really know how to prove it, or if it doesn't hold, find a counterexample.

Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: Sorry, accidentally put in the wrong exponent.

Comment: If $m$ is odd, then $10^{mn}+1$ is a multiple of $10^n+1$.  So you only have to worry when the exponent is a power of 2: $10^{2^n}+1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $10^{mn}+1$ is a multiple of $10^n+1$ when $m$ is odd, the only way you can have a prime is when the exponent has no odd factors above 1, so the exponent is a power of 2.
The following page has results for $b^{2^n}+1$ where $b$ is any even number.  It refers to these numbers as 'Generalised Fermat' numbers, because $2^{2^n}+1(n=0..4)$ are the Fermat primes.
http://yves.gallot.pagesperso-orange.fr/primes/results.html
They show, since $10$ appears in the first row and not other rows, that $10^2+1$ is prime, but the others up to and including $10^{32768}+1$ are composite.

Comment: Very interesting. But I don't understand why $10^n+1$ divides $10^{mn}+1$ if $m$ odd.

Comment: $(10^n+1)(10^{(m-1)n}-10^{(m-2)n}+....-10^n+1)=10^{mn}+1$.  It is the same reason that $11$ is a factor of $1001$ or $100001$

Comment: Yup. I got it before you answered, which is pedagogically optimal, nichts war? Use $10^{n(2k+1)}+1=(10^n)^{2k+1}-(-1)^{2k+1}$.

Comment: But are there any other primes $10^{2^k}+1$ than the one for $k=1$?

Comment: It seems they have tested them up to $10^{2^{15}}+1$, and no others were prime.  There may or may not be primes later on.